# Split user inputted string to char array

Tags: arrays, c, char

I'm making an appointment calendar program with c. My program adds an new appointment with user inputted command: "A 'description' 'mm' 'dd' 'hh'"
Where description is a string with a maximum of 20 characters, mm is months, dd is days and hh is hours. Months, days and hours can be 1 or 2 characters long.
I have tried to implement readInput function which splits the input string by spacebar and returns a char array which contains: [description, mm, dd, hh] so I can easily get:

```
desc = array[1];
month = array[2];
day = array[3];
hour = array[4];
```

Implementing this function was harder than I thought and I have failed miserably. I don't want pointers, just a basic char array containing strings. How should I implement this? Below is my main function.

```
int main()
{   
    struct Calendar c;
    c.numOfAppointments = 0;
    while (true) {
        char str[30];
        printf("Command: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
        if (str[0] == 'A')
        {
            char command = readInput(str); /*implement this */
        }
        else if (str[0] == 'L')
        {
            printCalendar(c);
        }
        else if (str[0] == 'Q')
        {
            printf("Exiting program...");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Say I input: A dentist 4 20 10

the returned array should be: ["dentist","4","20","10"]

Comment: Thanks for adding the example data.  You said you wanted the result as a "char array" (char *) but your example output is array of strings  (char **).  Why don't you want the result as a struct instead?

Comment: What is the "A " before dentist?

Answer (score 1):

> Implementing this function was harder than I thought and I have failed miserably.

Don't be so hard on yourself... you're learning. We learn to program mainly through our mistakes :-)

> I don't want pointers, just a basic char array containing strings.

Ah, so, there's your problem: Will it be an array of characters, or an array of strings?

A string in C is a pointer to a sequence of characters in memory ending with a `\0`.

An "array of strings" is an array of pointers!

What you could do is:

1. Read your line into a proper array of characters.
2. Place '\0' at appropriate places in this array, to indicate the end of line components.
3. Have a second array, e.g. `const char * array_of_fields[4]`, whose elements are strings.

or

3. Have a `struct { const char* description, month, day, hour; }`

and then

4. Set the elements of the second array, or the elements of the struct, to point to the appropriate positions within the character array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets(str, strlen(str), stdin)` to read in your string.  The next step is is to parse the string.  As your input consist of a variable description followed by a somewhat variable date time format.  The way to parse is to start at the end to find the separator `sep` between description and month which would be the 3rd last space (`n = 2`).  You now know whatever is before `sep` is "A " prefix and description, and everything after is the date time. You can use `strptime`(3) to parse the date time:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int rindexn(const char *s, char c, size_t n) {
    int i = strlen(s);
    if(!i) return -1;
    for(i--; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(s[i] == c) {
            if(!n) break;
            n--;
        }
    }
    return i >= 0 ? i : -1;
}

int main() {
    const char *str = "A dentist 4 20 10";

    // parse
    if(!strncmp(str, "A ", 2)) {
        printf("A space prefix missing");
        return 1;
    }
    int sep = rindexn(str, ' ', 2);
    if(sep == -1) {
        printf("sep not found\n");
        return 1;
    }
    struct tm tm;
    char *end = strptime(str + sep + 1, "%m %d %H", &tm);
    if(!end) {
        pritnf("cannot parse date time\n");
        return 1;
    } else if(*end) {
        printf("extra data after hour\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // convert to whatever format you decide
    printf("description = \"%.*s\", month = %d, day = %d, hour = %d",
        (int) sep - 2, str + 2, tm.tm_mon, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour);
}
```

which gives the following output:

```
description = "dentist", month = 3, day = 20, hour = 10
```